# bug with database values in leaflet pop ups

Tags: javascript, meteor, leaflet

I am building a project using leaflet and meteor where the user can enter text and have that text displayed in a popup when they click on the map. I can get the text to display initially, but the text display is lost on refresh.

```
var Markers = new Meteor.Collection('markers');
Meteor.subscribe('markers');

Template.map.rendered = function() {

map = L.map('map', {doubleClickZoom: false}).locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});

 //adds markers on dblclick
map.on('dblclick', function(event) {
currentlatlng = event.latlng;
Markers.insert({latlng: event.latlng});

});

var query = Markers.find();
query.observe({

added: function (document) {
  var marker = L.marker(document.latlng).addTo(map)
    .on('dblclick', function(event) {
      map.removeLayer(marker);
      Markers.remove({_id: document._id});
    });

    //display user input in popup
    var value;
    value = $("#txt_name").val();
    Markers.insert({txt: value});    
    marker.bindPopup(Markers.findOne({txt: value}).txt).openPopup();    

}
);//end observe
}
```

I know that because on refresh, `value` (which is just a text field in the html) is blank, it won't return anything. How can I have it always display the corresponding database field? The only way I've done it so far is by using `{{handlebars}}` in the html, which doesn't seem possible with leaflet popups.

Answer (score 0):

The `txt` is a completely different document than the `latLng` & the two are not related in any way in the DB. When you create a new marker, you need to include the `txt`. With few exceptions, you should focus on making every document within the Markers collection follow the same schema.

Comment: ah, i didn't know documents cannot be added later. so the `txt` should be inserted at the same time the `latlng` is inserted?

Comment: map.on('dblclick', function(event) {
    currentlatlng = event.latlng;
    value = $("#txt_name").val();
    Markers.insert({latlng: event.latlng, txt: value});

  });

Comment: there ya go, that should do it.